# RMarkdown: How to export and import code chunks?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to know if there is a way to import an external file, let's say, my_script.py as a code chunk in Rmarkdown and export a code chunk and convert into a standalone file.

The reason behind me asking this is so that some files are standalone from the RMarkdown document.

For example, from below, export the python code into a my_script.py file.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

## Header

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip

```{python}
x = 10
y = 20

z = x + y
print(z)
```
````

Comment: Thank you. I added the code in the edit.

Comment: Are you just looking for the `knitr::purl()` command? That extracts code chunks from Rmd files.

Comment: This works great. But, I am unable to make it work on the python code chunk. Any idea why?